# Is there any meaning to the first Hatsuyuki Sakura OP "freak of nature: start"?

Tags: symbolism, theme-song, hatsuyuki-sakura

The visual novel Hatsuyuki Sakura has 3 opening themes, namely "freak of nature: start" by I've, "Presto" by Kotoko, and "Hesitation Snow" by fripSide. The latter two have lyrics and a lot of images, so it's pretty easy to tell roughly what they're supposed to mean (basically, they're standard VN OP sequences).

However, the first is just vocalized, with very few character images (mostly just scenery), and thus it's hard to interpret exactly what it's supposed to mean. It plays very early in the novel (i.e. after 3 days, which is just the beginning of the prologue), and at that point the story really hasn't been established at all yet.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_R8jJE2b84

What symbolic connection does this song have to the novel? Is it supposed to mean anything, or just set a certain mood? Also, what is the significance of the title "freak of nature: start" to the novel?